# Include template before a loop

Tags: categories

This is my category / archive page

i want to include a template before loop

but i cant get posts based on category, it showing latest post only on every page.

when i removed this line before the loop

```
<?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/tb/hot_posts.tpl.php' ); ?>
```

it work smoothly, but i need this template before the loop

this is code (archive / category )

```
<div class="Hot_post">

<?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/tb/hot_posts.tpl.php' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : $count = 0; ?>
```

---

and this is code from template (includes/tb/hot_posts.tpl.php)

```
 <?php query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&order=DESC'); ?> 
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (   have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try and add

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

at the end of your template. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing at all to do with including a template-part file (for which, by the way, you should be using `get_template_part()` or `locate_template()`), and everything to do with **Doing It Wrong** with respect to [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

If you're trying to *override* the main Loop query, then you need to make sure you're doing so correctly. If you need to maintain the default query context, and *append* query arguments, then you have to maintain the default `$wp_query`. The easiest way to do so is as described in the Codex:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

To use your custom arguments, for example:

```
// Globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// Define custom query args
$custom_query_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
// Merge custom query args with default query
$custom_query = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $custom_query_args );
// Query posts based on modified query arguments
query_posts( $custom_query );
```

If, by chance, you're intending to perform a *secondary* loop, then you don't want to use `query_posts()` at all, but instead need to use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).